# Windows Phone 7 Font Styles

Tags: silverlight, fonts, windows-phone-7

I'm looking at [Fonts for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806365(v=VS.95).aspx) and noticed that the font list includes both fonts and 2 of its 3 available styles of its styles (Bold and Italic, but not Bold Italic). For example:

- Arial

  - Arial Bold
  - Arial Italic
  - (missing: Arial BoldItalic)

Does this mean that the style ***Bold Italic*** is explicitly not available in ROM on WP7 (for those fonts that have this style, such as Arial, Verdana, Georgia, Times New Roman, Courier New, Trebuchet MS)? Also, one other font, Segoe UI, only has one extra font style on that page - Bold - but it does have Italic and Bold Italic versions.

Reason I'm asking is because I need to determine which fonts to embed with Blend for WP7 font.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested and it does look like Times New Roman "Bold Italic" is included on WP7 (the letter "u" is the give away). It's much harder to visibly see if this style is available for the other fonts, in particular the sans-serif ones, but if Times New Roman is any indication, I'd guess all are available in this style.